# Ubuntu can't resolve hostname

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, ip, pi

i have a pi stack with some raspberry pi 3b+ and gave them hostnames (raspi1, raspi2, raspi3...) to connect with ssh.
So far i worked with Windows 11 and putty.
I just entered the hostname and was successfully connected to the Raspis.

Now i use a second Laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 on it. The same procedure and structure, but now it says:

> Unable to open connection to raspi1: the name or service is not
> known

If i try to connect it with the IP adress it still works.

For a minimum reproduction of the error i connected the laptop directly to the raspis.

Windows: connection with ip adress and hostname successful

Linux: ip adress successful, hostname not

Propably a DNS issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to use the network IP when going between Linux machines. WIndows is the only one that can connect with actual names. The only time you would have an issue is if the IP address does not work from either OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I thought something like that, unfortunately i have not much experience yet.
Is there no way to connect to the hostname?
Must change the IP address manually from time to time, a static IP address would not be ideal.

Comment: Can you save your Putty login settings or are there too many eyes over your shoulder?